# How to fix Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, eslint

Hi on npm install i got this error:
how can i solve it without using --force or --legacy-peer-deps?
i tried to looking for similar problems but all the suggestion is to using the above flags.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @babel/eslint-parser@7.18.2
npm ERR! Found: eslint@5.16.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"^5.16.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"*" from @typescript-eslint/experimental-utils@2.34.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils 
npm ERR!     @typescript-eslint/experimental-utils@"^2.5.0" from eslint-plugin-jest@23.20.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/eslint-plugin-jest
npm ERR!       dev eslint-plugin-jest@"^23.7.0" from the root 
project
npm ERR!   8 more (babel-eslint, eslint-config-prettier, eslint-loader, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^7.5.0 || ^8.0.0" from @babel/eslint-parser@7.18.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@babel/eslint-parser
npm ERR!   @babel/eslint-parser@"^7.16.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@8.19.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^7.5.0 || ^8.0.0" from @babel/eslint-parser@7.18.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@babel/eslint-parser
npm ERR!     @babel/eslint-parser@"^7.16.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry       
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps     
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

this is my package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "ng_starter",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "ng_starter",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "webpack-cli serve --mode development --env=development --hot",
        "mock": "webpack-cli serve --mode development --env=mock --hot",
        "prod": "webpack-cli build --mode production --env=production",
        "devprod": "webpack-cli build --mode development --env=devprod",
        "test": "jest --env=jsdom",
        "test-dev": "jest --env=jsdom --watch",
        "lint-fix": "eslint --fix  --ext .js --ext .jsx src"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.16.5",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.7.1",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "catalogone-ui-components": "1.16.0",
        "catalogone-ui-utility": "1.16.0",
        "classnames": "2.2.6",
        "d3-hierarchy": "^3.1.1",
        "i18next": "17.0.3",
        "connected-react-router": "^6.9.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "prop-types": "15.7.2",
        "query-string": "^6.10.1",
        "react": "16.8.6",
        "react-dom": "16.8.6",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
        "react-redux-i18n": "^1.9.2",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
        "redux-actions": "^2.6.5",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "validator": "^12.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "7.12.10",
        "@babel/core": "7.12.10",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.12.1",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.12.12",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "7.12.1",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind": "7.12.1",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "7.12.1",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "7.12.7",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.10",
        "@babel/preset-env": "7.12.11",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
        "@babel/register": "7.12.10",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
        "babel-plugin-istanbul": "5.2.0",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "3.2.0",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.1",
        "css-loader": "2.1.1",
        "eslint": "^5.16.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
        "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jest": "^23.7.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.2.0",
        "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.0",
        "file-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
        "jest": "^25.1.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.2",
        "mocker-api": "^2.9.4",
        "node-sass": "npm:sass@1.32.8",
        "prettier": "1.19.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
        "sass-loader": "7.1.0",
        "sass-resources-loader": "2.0.1",
        "source-map-loader": "^1.1.3",
        "style-loader": "0.23.1",
        "svg-transform-loader": "^2.0.13",
        "url-loader": "2.0.0",
        "webpack": "^4.44.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3",
        "webpack-merge": "^5.7.3"
    }
}
```

It seems to me like I have babel/eslint-parser@7.18.2
but I'm not totally sure how to solve this